# I have a class instance, how can I force execute its constructor which take object itself as a parameter

Tags: c#

This is what I am doing,

```
public class Order
{
    // defined all properties here
   public Order() {}

   // I want this constructor to run each time I do o.Add();
   public Order(Order o) {
        this.ID = o.ID;
        this.Title = o.Title;
        this.Status = CalculateStatus(o); 
        this._StartDate = GetDate(o.StartDate);
        this._EndDate = GetDate(o.EndDate);
   }

   public Order Add()
   {
        // other business logic
        this.ID = new OrderDataAccess().AddOrder(this.Title, this.Status, this._StartDate, this._EndDate);
        return this;
   }
}

public Order[] AddOrders(Order[] orderCollections)
{
        foreach(Order o in orderCollections)
        {
                o = new Order(o).Add();
        }

        // return object with update order's ID
        return orderCollections; 
}
```

**Where I am Stuck**

```
    foreach(Order o in orderCollections)
    {
            o = new Order(o).Add();
    }
```

**Error**

> Cannot assign to "o" because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

Please don't tell me what error means as I know what I am trying to do is wrong, I can't pass iterate and update object "o" at same time, but I am stuck with how to fix this issue following best practices.

**Edit**

Because AddOrders is a WCF method, I am not sure when it receives paramters with collections of objections, it runs my constructor Order (Order o) or not, let say WCF is calling this method from JS rest call, how WCF is going to know if I want it to intialize my object with constructor `Order (Order o)`

I want this constructor `Order(Order o)`  to run each time I do `o.Add();`

**Edit 2**

Sequence of execution I always want..

- Whenever order object calls Add, it must need to go through 2nd constructor `Order(Order o)` because, I also have update, delete functions which I didn't added to keep this simple, my seconds constructors updates properties as needed using my dataAccess layer, I can't trust WCF clients providing me data I exactly need.

I am pretty new to OOP, I don't understand the concept how calling WCF method AddOrders will ever execute my seconds constructor without me creating an instance of object again, and if I create a new instance to call 2nd constructor, I am not sure how to update references of objects WCF is initializing in it's array.

Comment: would `o.Add()` not be enough? (no need to reassign o at all)

Comment: You need to explain in words what you are trying to do. Is it to replace the contents of `orderCollections`? If so, you need to iterate over the indices instead of over the contents.

Comment: use a for loop instead

Comment: @Sayse I am confused with, as if o.Add will call my constructor Order(Order o) or not, as AddOrders is a WCF method getting parameters from other system

Comment: I can't see why you need to call the constructor at all, you seem to be just updating a property of the order

Comment: @Sayse constructor will get some data from my dataAccess layer and update some other properties that I didn't added here,

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `Add`-method without any assignment:

```
foreach(Order o in orderCollections)
{
    o.Add();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is neither any reason to `return this` from your `Add` method, nor is there any reason to update the object being enumerated!

Your `Add` method mutates the object itself, any reference you have to that object will be updated.

```
public Order[] AddOrders(Order[] orderCollections)
{
        foreach(Order o in orderCollections)
        {
                o.Add();
        }

        // orderCollections maintains REFERENCES to orders, so they all have their ID updated
        return orderCollections; 
}
```

As `AddOrders` is a WCF call, when it serializes the result the `ID` property of each order will have been filled by the call to `Add`, and the caller will receive it.

I'm still slightly concerned that the object you're communicating to the caller knows about Data Access, but that's a different story.

Comment: AddOrder is a actually a WCF Service, not Add, sorry :(

Comment: @Mathematics - no you said that, I read it wrong ;) Same principle though. My first, and original point is valid in that case.

Comment: I tested the way you advised, but then my 2nd constructor doesn't executes automatically